# Thread synchronization in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, semaphore

in my application I use different threads (one for every active transfer).
I would for example want to limit the active tranfers, putting the other coming ones in a queue.

For now my solution was checking if there was space for another active transfer, if not I would put the request in a queue list. Everytime I've a completed event, I pick one from the queue. (but I guess that my solution is really dirty)

Is there a nice way to schedule the active threads?

Is using a semaphore a nice (and neat) choice?

Comment: Check out `System.Threading.ThreadPool`, especially `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`.

Comment: You should probably show some code, show what you have tried and tell what didn't work with that solution and what you want to happen

Comment: what type of "transfer" is it? (file, network?) generally, it is not a good practive to dedicate threads for IO intensive operations.

Comment: I don't see why your current solution is dirty at all :)

Comment: @ErenErsönmez, I'm working with Azure storage, so I guess all of my  transfers are network based. I'm currently using async to manage the transfers. Was it a bad choice?

Comment: @Moo-Juice I just want to keep my code clean, I've to admit I'm pretty new to programming, I'm just trying not to take bad habits while I learn :P Thanks tho :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use a BlockingCollection to manage the queue, for example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Demo
{
    public class Program
    {
        private readonly BlockingCollection<int> _queue = new BlockingCollection<int>();

        private void run()
        {
            const int CONSUMER_COUNT = 8;

            Task[] tasks = new Task[CONSUMER_COUNT];

            for (int i = 0; i < CONSUMER_COUNT; ++i)
            {
                int id = i;
                tasks[i] = Task.Run(() => process(id));
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press <return> to start adding to the queue.");
            Console.ReadLine();

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Adding item #{0}", i);
                _queue.Add(i);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press <return> to close the queue.");
            Console.ReadLine();

            _queue.CompleteAdding();

            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for all tasks to exit.");
            Task.WaitAll(tasks);

            Console.WriteLine("Finished waiting for all tasks. Press <return> to exit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private void process(int id)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Process {0} is starting.", id);

            foreach (var item in _queue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Process {0} is processing item# {1}", id, item);
                Thread.Sleep(200); // Simulate long processing time.
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Process {0} is stopping.", id);
        }

        private static void Main()
        {
            new Program().run();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the crucial thing here is that `GetConsumingEnumerable()` returns an enumerable which will block if there are no items in the queue, but which will exit if there no items *and* the producer has called `CompleteAdding()`. This makes it quite easy to control when the worker threads exit.